# Advent of code 2023 day 8: Path finding in the desert - in pure Bash

Tags: programming-challenge, bash

#### Part 1

In [today's task](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/8), a network of paths is defined like this:

> ```
> LLR
>
> AAA = (BBB, BBB)
> BBB = (AAA, ZZZ)
> ZZZ = (ZZZ, ZZZ)
> ```

The first line `LLR` is instructions to follow to change position.

- When the current instruction is `L`, change position to the left value of the pair.

  - For example at position `BBB` the left value is `AAA`.
- When the current instruction is `R`, change position to the right value of the pair.

  - For example at position `BBB` the right value is `ZZZ`.
- The instructions loop around, so when reaching the last symbol, then start over from the first.

The task is to count the steps to reach from `AAA` to `ZZZ`. In the above example it takes 6 steps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/8 part 1
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day8part1.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

solve_2023_day8_part1() {
  local instructions
  read -r instructions

  # Consume empty line.
  read -r

  local -A leftmap
  local -A rightmap
  local line pos left right

  while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ (...)\ =\ \((...),\ (...)\) ]]
    pos=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    left=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    right=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

    leftmap[$pos]=$left
    rightmap[$pos]=$right
  done

  local i=0 steps=0
  pos="AAA"

  while [[ "$pos" != "ZZZ" ]]; do
    if [[ ${instructions:i:1} = "L" ]]; then
      pos=${leftmap[$pos]}
    else
      pos=${rightmap[$pos]}
    fi

    ((++steps))
    ((++i))
    ((i == ${#instructions})) && i=0
  done

  echo "$steps"
}

solve_2023_day8_part1
```

#### Part 2

For part 2, we are told that instead of just `AAA`, all positions that end with `A` are start positions, for example `XXA` would also be a start position. We are to move in parallel from all start positions, until all the positions end with `Z` at the same time.

After a few quick experiments it's easy to see that all start positions in the input arrive at positions ending with `Z` in regular cycles. Therefore, to determine the number of steps when all the positions end with `Z` at the same time, we can compute the least common multiple of all the individual cycle lengths.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/8 part 2
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day8part2.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

compute_gcd() {
  local a=$1
  local b=$2
  local temp

  while ((b > 0)); do
    ((temp = b))
    ((b = a % b))
    ((a = temp))
  done

  echo "$a"
}

compute_lcm() {
  local a=$1
  local b=$2
  local gcd

  gcd=$(compute_gcd "$a" "$b")
  echo $((a * b / gcd))
}

solve_2023_day8_part2() {
  local instructions
  read -r instructions

  # Consume empty line.
  read -r

  local -A leftmap
  local -A rightmap
  local line pos left right

  while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ (...)\ =\ \((...),\ (...)\) ]]
    pos=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    left=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    right=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

    leftmap[$pos]=$left
    rightmap[$pos]=$right
  done

  local i steps lcm=1

  for pos in "${!leftmap[@]}"; do
    [[ "$pos" == ??A ]] || continue

    i=0
    steps=0

    while [[ "$pos" != ??Z ]]; do
      if [[ ${instructions:i:1} = "L" ]]; then
        pos=${leftmap[$pos]}
      else
        pos=${rightmap[$pos]}
      fi
      
      ((++steps))
      ((++i))
      ((i == ${#instructions})) && i=0
    done

    lcm=$(compute_lcm "$lcm" "$steps")
  done

  echo "$lcm"
}

solve_2023_day8_part2
```

#### Review request

I know this is a bit whimsical, and Bash is a poor choice to solve algorithmic puzzles. Also, this code is intended as a one-off, and not for reuse. I'm solving in Bash because, and as long as, it gives me joy. My main goals are:

- Compute the correct solution to the full input within seconds.
- Use idiomatic Bash.
- Easy to read and understand.

Do you see any patterns here that you would replace with better patterns?

Do you see a simpler way to solve any part of the puzzle with Bash and common shell tools?

What would you do differently?